# How can I create a stopwatch using date.now() in JS?

Tags: javascript, timer

I would like to know how you could create a simple count up timer using date.now.
I would like to use date.now() to find the start time and date.now() to get the current time and subtract the two to get the elapsed time in javascript?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you would do it. Have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one I just built, Press "Run code snippet" at the bottom to test it out. Comment if you need further explanation.

```js
var prevTime, stopwatchInterval, elapsedTime = 0;

var updateTime = function () {
  var tempTime = elapsedTime;
  var milliseconds = tempTime % 1000;
  tempTime = Math.floor(tempTime / 1000);
  var seconds = tempTime % 60;
  tempTime = Math.floor(tempTime / 60);
  var minutes = tempTime % 60;
  tempTime = Math.floor(tempTime / 60);
  var hours = tempTime % 60;
  
  var time = hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
  
  $("#time").text(time);
};

$("#startButton").click(function () {
  if (!stopwatchInterval) {
    stopwatchInterval = setInterval(function () {
      if (!prevTime) {
        prevTime = Date.now();
      }
      
      elapsedTime += Date.now() - prevTime;
      prevTime = Date.now();
      
      updateTime();
    }, 50);
  }
});

$("#pauseButton").click(function () {
  if (stopwatchInterval) {
    clearInterval(stopwatchInterval);
    stopwatchInterval = null;
  }
  prevTime = null;
});

$("#resetButton").click(function () {
  $("#pauseButton").click();
  elapsedTime = 0;
  updateTime();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  updateTime();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Time: <span id="time"></span><br>

<button id="startButton">Start</button>
<button id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
<button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see Winestone's answer so I made an example in  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrzngubj/8/).

In a nutshell anyway:

```
var start=Date.now(),
stop=Date.now(),
diff=stop-start;
```

All the remaining fiddling you may need is for formatting time in milliseconds decently, and get the wanted delay between start and stop.